# Diferencia entre métodos y estáticos en Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

¿Quiero saber cual es la diferencia entre los **estáticos** y los **métodos** en `Mongoose` ?

Lo que entendí es que los métodos son instancias al crear un nuevo objeto y los estáticos se llaman sin necesidad de instanciar o de que forma se pueden diferenciar, lei en la documentación pero no encontré mucha información

```
usuarioEsquema.methods.generaToken = function ()  {
  const user = this
  console.log(user)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás tan lejos, sin embargo dado tienes una pequeña duda trataré de aclararla de ser posible.

**MÉTODO**

Antes que nada, vamos a definir lo que es un método, ya que en realidad estamos hablando exclusivamente de ellos.

Según la Wikipedia, un [método](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) es una subrutina o subprograma (puedes llamarle función si te parece más claro, aunque no necesariamente devuelva o retorne un valor), que puede ser declarado (pertenece) tanto en una [Clase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clase_(inform%C3%A1tica)) como en un [Objeto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_(programaci%C3%B3n)). Asumo que entiendes la diferencia entre Clase y Objeto.

En el caso que el método pertenezca a una clase se le conoce como *[método estático](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods)*. Una traducción de la Wikipedia podría ser:

> Los métodos estáticos se entienden como (o están destinados a ser) relevantes para todas las instancias de una Clase en vez de a cualquier instancia específica.

Esto quiere decir que dicho método no forma parte de la instancia de una clase (no está disponible en la instancia de la clase).

Por otro lado, cuando un método pertenece a un Objeto (instancia de la clase) se le conoce como *método de instancia*. Y el mismo sólo estará disponible para ser usado por la instancia creada.

Un método estático se puede invocar sin necesidad de crear una instancia de la clase. Reciben su nombre debido que son *resueltos* durante el tiempo de compilación de acuerdo a la Clase a la que pertenecen, siendo estos constantes o inmutables (estáticos), a diferencia de los métodos de instancia que se resuelven en tiempo de ejecución, siendo de alguna manera *dinámicos* (resueltos por [polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29) de acuerdo al tipo de Objeto que se está instanciando).

**Mongoose: Métodos Estáticos vs. Métodos de Instancia**

Ahora, para explicar las diferencias entre ambos en Mongoose, debemos dejar claro primero la diferencia entre *Schema*, *Model* y *Document*.

Un [*Schema*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) o Esquema, es la definición de los elmentos o características de un documento dentro de una Colección de Mongo. Cada *Schema* guarda relación con una colección de la base de datos, no con un documento, sino con toda la colección. Es un *fingerprint* de los documentos que están almacenados en la colección.

Un [*Modelo*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html), es un constructor compilado a partir de la definición de un Esquema. Nos permite crear Documentos asociados a una colección de MongoDB. Todo Modelo de Mongoose se compila a partir de un *Schema*.

Un [*Documento*](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), por otra parte, es una instancia de un Modelo y guarda una relación directa con un documento almacenado en una colección de nuestra Base de Datos.

Mongoose define dos tipos de métodos: Estáticos y de Instancia. Dado que un Documento es una instancia de un Modelo, ya tenemos una idea de en dónde aplica cada uno.

Sin embargo, ambas familias son declaradas como parte de un objeto perteneciente al *Schema*.

Los métodos estáticos pertenecen (o son declarados) como parte del objeto `statics` del esquema (`Schema.statics`). Dichos métodos sólo podrán ser usados directamente desde la Clase `Model`. Cada Modelo creado a partir del *Schema* que contiene el método podrá hacer uso del mismo. En Mongoose, cuando se declara un método estático, la palabra `this` (usada dentro del método) hará referencia al Modelo.

Los métodos de instancia pertenecen (o son declarados) como parte del objeto `methods` del esquema (`Schema.methods`). Los métodos así declarados sólo son accesibles (están disponibles) desde un Documento. Cada documento creado a partir del Modelo tendrá acceso al método de instancia. En Mongoose, cuando se declara un método de instancia, la palabra `this` (usada dentro del método) hará referencia al Documento.

Aclarados estos puntos, falta decir, ¿cuándo usar uno u otro?

Pues eso va a depender de lo que necesites hacer.

Si se trata de operaciones que van a requerir el uso de propiedades específicas de un documento, se deben usar métodos de instancia.

En cambio si se trata de operaciones globales sobre una colección de documentos, pues lo apropiado es usar un método estático.

**EJEMPLO**

Probemos un ejemplo práctico para finalizar y tal vez de esta forma podamos entender aún más los conceptos aquí planteados.

Primero crearemos una colección en MongoDB llamada `animals`:

```
let documents = [
  {name: 'Bob', type: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Kit', type: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Apaloosa', type: 'horse'},
  {name: 'Chippewa', type: 'horse'},
  {name: 'Loki', type: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Bud', type: 'dog'},
  {name: 'Whiskers', type: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Daisy', type: 'dog'},
];

db.animals.insertMany(documents);
```

Ahora usando Mongoose desde una aplicación Express podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Creamos un esquema
const animalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, type: String});

// Ejemplo de Static Method
//========================================================================
// Creamos un método estático que será compilado en el modelo creado a partir
// del esquema. Podemos usar este método estático directamente desde el modelo,
// sin necesidad de instanciar un documento. Si tratamos de llamar al método desde
// un documento instanciado el mismo fallará.
//

// Asignamos un Método Estático al objeto 'statics'  de 'animalSchema'
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function(name, cb) {
  return this.find({name: new RegExp(name, 'i')}, cb);
}

// Otra forma de declarar un método estático es usando la función 'static()'
animalSchema.static('countHorses', function(cb) {
  this.find({type: 'horse'}, (err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      return cb(err, null);
    }
    let horses = results.length;
    return cb(null, horses);
  });
});

// Ejemplo de Método de Instancia
//======================================================================
// Creamos un método de instancia que será compilado para cada documento
// creado a partir del modelo. No podemos llamar el método directamente desde el
// modelo  como lo hacemos con un método estático. Si lo intentamos llamar fallará.
//

// Asignamos un método de instancia al objeto 'methods' de 'animalSchema'
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function(cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({type: this.type}, cb);
}

// Otra forma de declarar métodos de instancia es usando la función 'method()'
animalSchema.method('meow', function() {
  this.type === 'cat' ? console.log('Meeeeeoooooooooow') : console.log('Dude, I\'m not a cat' );
});

// Creamos un Modelo: Animal, a partir de animalSchema, este modelo tiene los métodos
// estáticos creados anteriormente
const Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);

// Instanciamos dos documentos basados en el modelo Animal , this document has an instance method
// Esta instancia del modelo representa un documento cuyo valor 'type' es 'dog'
let dog = new Animal({type: 'dog'});

// Llamadas a métodos de instancia desde el documento 'dog'
dog.meow();

dog.findSimilarTypes((err, dogs) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log('List of dogs:');
  console.log(dogs);
});

// Llamadas a los métodos estáticos sobre el modelo Animal
let name = 'Bob'

Animal.findByName(name, (err, results) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log('List of Animals whose name is ', name);
  console.log(results);
});

Animal.countHorses((err, numHorses) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`There's actually ${numHorses} horses in the farm.`);
});
```

Como se puede apreciar en el código, se han creado dos métodos de instancia y dos métodos estáticos.

Si deseamos obtener todos los animales que tengan un nombre en particular, se debe realizar una búsqueda sobre toda la colección. Es por ello que el método `findByName()` ha sido declarado como estático, ya que es el Modelo el que apunta a la colección `animals`.

Si deseamos que nuestro gato diga `meow`, usaremos un método de instancia, ya que nos estamos refiriendo a un documento específico de tipo `cat`.

También vemos que si deseamos contar la cantidad de caballos de nuestra colección, podríamos usar un método estático que realiza el conteo sobre toda la colección. Claro existen métodos incluidos en Mongoose que realizan dicha tarea, como [`count()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) o [`estimatedDocumentCount()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount).

Si ejecutas el código anterior la salida puede verse parecida a la siguiente:

[image: Resultados]

Espero que esto te ayude a aclarar la duda.